# How can I tell if I am on track for the Genocide ending?

Tags: undertale

I'm doing a Genocide run of Undertale now, which involves killing literally everyone (not only ending all encounters with a fight, but hunting down every monster in an area and killing them). The problem I'm currently having with this is I have to count, and I don't want to count. That, and I'm certain I'm going to miss some counting. Is there any way to know for sure that the Genocide ending will happen at a given point in a run?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's no need to count the number of enemies in each area. Just **keep killing enemies in the area until you get the *"But nobody came"* message in your random encounters**. This means you have killed all the enemies in this area and you can continue on to the boss. *Be sure you finish this before approaching the area's boss*, even if you can normally go back before actually fighting them.

Save points outside the Ruins also have a counter indicating how many enemies are left in the area.

When doing a Genocide run don't forget killing the dummy and the initial Froggit.

You can view a full list of all the enemies you need to kill [here](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Genocide_Route#Requirements).

Comment: The counter on save points appears only after you kill out the Ruins. And you have to kill everything before you go fight the area boss.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of ways that let know you are on the genocide route.

1. Instead of a `!` when you encounter a fight you show a `:)`.
2. The bosses say different messages than the Pacifist Route. Toriel: `You really hate me don't you?`
3. When you have killed enough monsters in the area you are in a message will pop up saying, `But nobody came.` in small letters.
4. Whenever you click the "Save Point" it does not say the messages you usually see. For example, `18 left.` When the number reaches to zero, the "Save Point" says, `Determination.` This means you have killed all the monsters in that area. Each number counts as one monster.