# Why did my genocide run say that it was a neutral run?

Tags: undertale

I was just killing every monster I encountered, but it still counted as a neutral run. Does anyone know why this happened?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I know how many enemies I need for the Genocide Route?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/247078/how-do-i-know-how-many-enemies-i-need-for-the-genocide-route)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell if I am on track for the Genocide ending?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/241045/72346)

Answer (score 12):

Genocide runs mean killing literally everything in the game.

Without giving away spoilers, each section of the game has a certain number of encounters that you have to clear. To do this, I usually just run around in the same area for as long as it takes me to clear the required number of kills.

Once you've killed everything, the music will change to a darker track, and that's when you know that you can continue on to the next section of the game. This is the part that most new players forget to do when doing genocide runs. Genocide implies killing *everything*.

Kill every boss you encounter, as well. That's a given.

If you aren't afraid of spoilers, you can look up [the specifics on how to do a genocide run on the wiki](https://undertale.fandom.com/wiki/Genocide_Route#:%7E:text=The%20Genocide%20Route%20occurs%20when,sub%2Dregion%20of%20Hotland).